# Return Visible/Unfiltered rows only using Excel Filter function

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I trying to load visible/unfiltered rows only from a Table (Table1) into a VBA array I can work with.
For that I was thing of using worksheetfunction.filter formula.

What can I use for the `Include` variable that would return an array of 0 and 1 if the row is hidden or not?

[image]

As a small example I have the table below:

[image]

Comment: Why a filter? Why not [**.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18270385/14094617)?

Comment: Agree with @JohnSUN, just be aware it will return an Area object for each contiguous set of visible rows. You'll just need to iterate over all the Areas collection to get to all the rows in the group of visible rows.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

doesn't always work in my experience. When I google it, I get the impression that it's not as straight forward to use as other functions. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095600/vba-specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-not-working-correctly-when-looping-through-p) illustrates how it doesn't seem so easy to use.

The second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943200/how-to-determine-if-a-worksheet-cell-is-visible-displayed-in-vba) provides a better solution for identifying whether a cell is visible or not.

I have used it myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73553240/using-countifs-in-vba-with-filtered-data/73555673#73555673

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).